# How to create an infinite scroll in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a select year by scrolling something like this:

[image]

I need the scroll to go both ways till maybe 0 to 9999, obviously I can't store that much value in a single array for a `<Flatlist>`

so I improvised and made it such that after reaching the end it would scroll back to the top
and reset to whatever the previous last year was +10 and it gave me this:

[image]

imp part of the source code:

```
function setrange(from = 2000, to=2010){
    let temp_arr = [{ key: 0, title: '' }];//so that the selected item always stays in middle
    let k=1;
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i++)
        temp_arr.push({ key: k++, title: i})
    temp_arr.push({ key: k , title: '' });//so that the selected item always stays in middle
    setDATA(temp_arr);
}

const [DATA, setDATA] = useState(...);

<FlatList
    onEndReached={() => { setrange(from=DATA[DATA.length-2]['title'],to=DATA[DATA.length-2]['title']+10); Scrollref.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: false, index: 0 });}}
    data={DATA}
    ref={Scrollref}
    ...
/>
```

the complete [source code](https://justpaste.it/99f62)

so how do I make it seem like an infinite scroll without stopping or loosing scroll momentum in between?
(also please don't recommend an external library if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to create your own implementation of lazy loading if you're only rendering plain texts with static height, since FlatList has already one built-in. You just need to play with it's props to make it perfect for your use case.

Creating an array with 10000 items of course costs you a bit of memory (it is actually lower than youd expect) but, it is up to you whether you want every bit of performance.

Here is a snack to test it: https://snack.expo.dev/@truetiem/date-picker

```
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 60;
const SEPERATOR_HEIGHT = 1;

<FlatList
  data={Array(9999)
    .fill('')
    .map((_, index) => (index + 1).toString())}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View
      style={{
        height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
    <View
      style={{ height: SEPERATOR_HEIGHT, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#ccc' }}
    />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
  getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({
    length: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    offset: (ITEM_HEIGHT * index) + (SEPERATOR_HEIGHT * index),
    index,
  })}
  initialScrollIndex={2019}
  initialNumToRender={10}
  windowSize={9}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  snapToInterval={ITEM_HEIGHT + SEPERATOR_HEIGHT}
  snapToAlignment={"center"}
/>
```

Comment: I mean your method works but doesn't seem like the most efficient way to implement, 
like you said 10000 items do cost a bit of memory so is there no way to render only when needed instead of creating all the 10000 items? or does the `initialNumToRender` limit it from actually being created?

Comment: I haven't tried to do something like this before but I don't think there would be a better solution where you won't loose scroll momentum. You would also constantly keep re-rendering to load new data. Also flatlist doesn't render all of the 10000 items at once, it renders according to initialNumToRender and windowSize props. We are only creating an array with 10000 items, and it only takes about 10mb of ram on IOS with hermes engine according to my performance profile results. Maybe someone smarter than me finds a better solution, but this is the best i've come with

Comment: btw when I tired your method for some reason the flatlist items were not snapping into place like this and the more you scroll down the more they would deviate from the snapLength like this https://i.ibb.co/SrTRgB1/image.png

Comment: You probably forgot to add the border (or item seperator component) height to the offset in the `getItemLayout` prop. It should match the exact position of each item. I've edited the linked snack example and the answer to match your needs.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/46vbn this works for me (for future reference) and what does `windowSize` do?

Comment: It limits how many items should be rendered on screen. eg. 9 means 1 in the center, your current view, 4 on top and 4 on the bottom. 1 unit is the viewport height. https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#windowsize

Comment: also when I change the ITEM_HEIGHT from 60 to 50 it starts deviating again, I am beyond confusion rn